# How to pop a lesser-sized value into a register

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

I have a 2-byte value stored on the stack and I would like to `pop` it into a register. I can do that on one of the general purpose registers by using the 16-bit register within it, such as:

```
popw %cx
```

Is there a way to put it into another register such as `r11` with zero-filling it? Something like:

```
popzwq %r11   # making up the syntax
```

Or what would be the proper way to do that?

Comment: Do you really only want to increment the stack pointer by 2? The stack is usually 8-byte aligned, so incrementing by 2 would be unusual.

Comment: `pop %r11`   `movzwq %r11w, %r11`

Comment: There are endless compound instructions the designers can introduce, and they will only spend time and circuits for something really useful. It is also a principle for the designers to keep an instruction set neat and atomic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you **avoid this in the first place by never using pushw, instead always use full-width (64-bit) stack slots when pushing / popping.**  That also keeps the stack aligned.  Also, normally you'd only use push/pop when entering / leaving a function, to save/restore registers.  (There are no calling conventions where the low part is call-preserved but not the upper bytes, and it's generally most efficient to save/restore full registers.)

But if you do need it, simply emulate it with 2 instructions.

```
   movzwl  (%rsp), %ecx          # or %r11d.  implicitly zero-extends into the full 64-bit reg
   add     $2, %rsp              # or if you need to preserve FLAGS,
                                 # lea 2(%rsp), %rsp
```

There aren't zero-extending forms of pop; 8086 could only pop full-width (16-bit) registers so there were no existing opcodes to modify.  And 386 didn't introduce any zero-extending pop equivalent to movzx or movsx; almost nobody would ever benefit from that: normal code uses full-width push/pop when it uses it at all.  (More common with legacy stack-args calling conventions that were common back then instead of modern efficient register args for the first few args.)
So it's not worth the cost in transistors and opcode coding space.

---

Or if you don't want to zero-extend, `pop %r11w`.  (Not sure if you didn't know the names of the low-8 / low-16 / low-32 registers for r8..r15, or why you didn't use RCX in your 2nd example to contrast with pop cx).

Comment: `add     $2, %rsp`. This scares me. Why would anyone ever do that?

Comment: @W.Chang: Because they're emulating `popw`.  Agreed that there's are extremely few cases where it makes any sense to do either of those things; that was the point of the first paragraph of this answer.  In asm there are boatloads of things that are possible but horrible.  e.g. under limited circumstances, you can use ESP or RSP as scratch space, holding a non-pointer.  (e.g. no signal handlers installed, and you're in user-space.  Still usually a bad idea, especially on x86-64 where you have 15 other regs, plus xmm0..15, instead of only 7 other 32-bit GPRs.)